# rails controller search db tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Simple question, I'm trying to work out how to search for a field that matches in two tables.

So for example, Table one has a url inside, As does table two, These both match

I'm loading up a row from table one into an edit view, How can i get the id that matches the url from table 2?

e.g.

Table one has in a column called url, `google.co.uk/12343`
Table two has the exact same url column name and data inside ( however it's going to be scanned over 24k times in the 2nd table)

The url is an exact match.

Basically i'm just needing a match to the url so i can get everything from that ID

Thanks

Sam

Comment: I havent tried this yet, however i didn't think it'd work, @tm = Master.find(params[:Masterurl])

Comment: assume `url` is your column name, the query will be @tm = Master.find_by(url: params[:Masterurl])

Comment: Also, you mentioned the edit, view. Do you want to get the matching `id` as soon as the user ends typing it? Or until the user submits the form?

Comment: Its to really auto populate some of the text fields @Leito

Comment: But on the same form or after submit?